# how to access a mySQL enum field with Java ResultSet and PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, enums

Quick question what's the correct way to use ResultSet and PreparedStatement to access an ENUM field in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

never did but I would use String, see the documentation:
[21.4.4.3. Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)